# factory creating different types according to enum values c++

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have some auto generated structs each logically related to a enum value.
can I create a factory using a template function?
everything can be resolved at compiled time.
I tried something like this:

```
struct Type1
{
};    

struct Type2
{
};

enum class type_t
{
    first,
    second
};

template <type_t typet>
auto Get_()
{    
    static_assert(typet == type_t::second);
    return Type2();
}  

template <type_t typet>
auto Get_()
{
    static_assert(typet == type_t::first);
    return Type1();
} 
   
template <type_t typet>
auto Get_()
{
    static_assert(false, "no overload");
}    

int main()
{
    auto relatedType1 = Get_<type_t::first>();
    auto relatedType2 = Get_<type_t::second>();
}
```

Comment: So you want a function that returns a new struct and the type of the struct is specified by the value you give to the factory function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 (and above), you may use an auxiliary traits struct like the following:

```
template <type_t T>
struct type_selector;

template <>
struct type_selector<type_t::first> {
    using type = Type1;
};

template <>
struct type_selector<type_t::second> {
    using type = Type2;
};

// implement other specializations, if needed
```

Then, your `Get_` function template is simply:

```
template <type_t typet>
auto Get_() -> typename type_selector<typet>::type {
    return {};
}
```